# How to get the selected value and key from an html dropdown list in javascript on php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
 <select id="facetList" style="width:120px;" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <?php
        foreach($claAddArray as $k => $v)
        {
           echo "<option value=\"$k\">$v</option>";
        }
        ?>   
        </select>




$("#btnSubmit").click(function() {

    var $fId = ?????????????????


    });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

jQuery's .val() will return the currently selected option's value if run on the select list itself. In your case `$("#facetList").val();`

use `$("#facetList option:selected").text();` for the text of the option tag.

Comment: The OP also asked for the label.

Comment: and `$("#facetList").children(":selected").html();` for $v

Comment: Mine's shorter. :) But yours is good too. (Wow.. I can't believe I said that...)

Comment: Yeah text is also a better function to use as html :). I'm wanna go back sleeping... `$("#facetList :selected").text();` would be even shorter.

Answer (score 4):

```
document.getElementById('facetList').options[document.getElementById('facetList').selectedIndex].value
```

Comment: works too, but jQuery is already being used so using .val() is a better choice.

Comment: Damp, I tried your solution as well. It's obviously shorter and easier, but why do you say it's better?
Also, what shall I change if I want to get the value or key instead?

Comment: So wanna get `$v`? I think this should do the trick: `document.getElementById('facetList').options[document.getElementById('facetList').selectedIndex].innerHTML`

Comment: It is shorter, and easier to read, and is how the framework intends for you to do it. Therefore it is better. However if you want other information, you'll need to go about it differently. Once you have the value, you can use it to 'look up' which object has that value. Raw JS is more powerful in that regard, but as you see, much harder to read.